# Pytorch: Most computationally and memory efficient way to make a series of concatenations from extracting tensor rows?

Tags: pytorch

Say that this is my sample tensor

```
sample = torch.tensor(
    [[2, 7, 3, 1, 1],
        [9, 5, 8, 2, 5],
        [0, 4, 0, 1, 4],
        [5, 4, 9, 0, 0]]
)
```

I want to have a new tensor, which will consist of concatenations of 2 rows from the sample tensor.

So I have a tensor which contains pairs of the row numbers that I want concatenated into a single row for the new tensor

```
cat_indices = torch.tensor([[0, 1], [1, 2], [0, 2], [2, 3]])
```

The current method I am using is this

```
torch.cat((sample[cat_indices[:,0]], sample[cat_indices[:,1]]), dim=1)
```

Which gives the desired result

```
tensor([[2, 7, 3, 1, 1, 9, 5, 8, 2, 5],
        [9, 5, 8, 2, 5, 0, 4, 0, 1, 4],
        [2, 7, 3, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 4],
        [0, 4, 0, 1, 4, 5, 4, 9, 0, 0]])
```

Is this the most memory and computationally efficient method of doing this? I am not sure because I am making two calls to `cat_indices`, and then I am doing a concatenation operation.

I feel that there should be a way to do this via some sort of view. Perhaps advanced indexing. I've tried things like `sample[cat_indices[:,0], cat_indices[:,1]]` or `sample[cat_indices[0], cat_indices[1]]` but I can't make the view come out right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have should be pretty fast. An alternative is

```py
sample[cat_indices].reshape(cat_indices.shape[0],-1)
```

You would have to benchmark the performance on your machine though to see which is better.

Comment: I'll point out in a comment that I do believe this should be faster since only one intermediate tensor (`sample[cat_indices]`) is actually constructed. `reshape` will return a view of that tensor, thus none of the data is actually being copied when you call `reshape`.